# Drag and Drop PDF file into word document using Python

Tags: python

I have to create a table in word document and insert the PDF file into the table using python. In this i have created the table and trying to insert the pdf file into the table but it's not working. Can anyone please suggest me, how to insert the pdf file using python. Attached the expected output image for reference.[Drag and Drop pdf file into word document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3W5X.jpg)

Comment: Where is the code that's causing the problem?

Comment: Actually am new to developing, so i don't know how to insert the pdf file in word document. I have the code for creating word document and inserting table, not for inserting pdf files